# CSS/HTML responsive nav bar

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

So, iam a beginner coder and started my first project, a responsive site with navbar and "hamburger" menu so that when you go to the mobile version, the "li /a href" elements disappear and the "3 stripes-menu thing" appears.
But now my problem is, the logo that is normally on the left aligns to the right and the menu icon is going to the left.

i need help there

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav">
        <label for="hamburger" id="hambox">&#9776</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger">
        <img id="logo_small" src="/Bilder/Logo_small.png" alt="">
        <div id="hamitems">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav label,
#hamburger {
  display: none;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #3d3f45;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.nav ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

#logo_small {
  max-height: 60px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav a:hover {
  color: brown;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  
  #hamitems {
    display: none;
  }
  #hamitems li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #nav label {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: green;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-style: normal;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  #hambox {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Put the logo image _before_ the label element then ...?

Comment: bruh, yeah i works hahahaha ty lmao

Comment: To make it easier you can use the framework bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/